# Editing Raleigh GTK theme

Tags: gtk, gtk3, gtk-2, gtkrc

There's the default GTK theme in XFCE called Raleigh. I would like to change the dark blue color (#4b6983) to something different. But if I go to */usr/share/themes/Raleigh/gtk-2.0/* and take a look at the *gtkrc* file all I get to see is this:

*This theme is the default theme if no other theme is selected.*

No chance to modify anything on that theme. What do I have to do in order to be able to edit this Raleigh theme?

Thanks in advance,
joecontra

Comment: Could you explain why you want to specifically use the Raleigh theme? I think you had an earlier query as well re. gtk3 and Raleigh. I tried finding useful information on Raleigh but couldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following lines to `~/.gtkrc-2.0`. Change the hexadecimal color `ff0000` to whatever you like.

```
style "default"
{
    base[SELECTED]  = "#ff0000"
}
class "GtkWidget"           style "default"
```